# Equality of String characters and usual character don't work / How to get indexes of those chars

Tags: java, string, char, compare

I am trying to compare the chars of user String with the 2 chars also got from user, and if one of them is equal to char of that String in particular index, so I need to print that index.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestIndexOf {

    private static String text;
    private  static char ch1, ch2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestIndexOf  test = new TestIndexOf();
        test.getInput();
        System.out.println(test.getIndex(text, ch1, ch2));
    }

    public static void getInput() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter word and chars: ");
        text = scan.nextLine();
      
        char ch1 = scan.next().charAt(0);
        char ch2 = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }

    public static int getIndex(String text, char ch1, char ch2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == ch1) {
                return i;
            }
            if (text.charAt(i) == ch1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get it without indexOf()

Comment: You check `ch1` twice in your `getIndex` method. Is that right?

Comment: Why do you have `if (text.charAt(i) == ch1) {` twice? I assume one of the two comparisons would have to be against ch2. Is it a typo?

Comment: Oww Sorry, it's a typo there should be if (text.charAt(i) == ch2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private  static char ch1, ch2;
....
char ch1 = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

This will not assign to ch1 but create a new variable in the getInput method scope, you need to do like this to get the result you expect.

```
ch1 = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: thanks, that's work, but  I need to get indexes of these 2 chars  when they are present in the string, and I am getting index only  one of them and  second is ignore for some reasons what I should do in this situation?

Comment: When you say `return i`, you exit the method. So if the first character is present you will never check for the second. You should return an array of int, and store the indexes in it instead of returning each index on its own if clause.

Comment: can you give me an example of code how to do it in your way please?

Comment: @DimaMargita you cant return 2 indexes at the same time without using arrays or some other ugly method, I would suggest making the getIndex method find one of them and then call it twice. `int getIndex(String text, char ch)`

Answer (score 0):

Your variables ch1 and ch2 are defined twice. First they are declared as static fields on your class but not initialized. Second, they are declared as local variables of `getInput` and initialized there, but as local variables they can't be accessed from outside the method.