# check two conditions in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am checking for 2 conditions, and I need that both of them would work,
but work only one of them. Where I am making the mistake? I need to print indexes of positions of ch1 and ch2  in String text

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestIndexOf {

    private static String text;
    private  static char ch1, ch2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestIndexOf  test = new TestIndexOf();
        test.getInput();
        System.out.println(test.getIndex(text, ch1, ch2));
    }

    public static void getInput() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter word and chars: ");
        text = scan.nextLine();

        ch1 = scan.next().charAt(0);
        ch2 = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }

    public static int getIndex(String text, char ch1, char ch2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
          if (text.charAt(i) == ch1) {
            return i;
           }
          if (text.charAt(i) == ch2) {
             return i;
          }
        }

      return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in greater detail. Exactly what behavior are you expecting but not getting?

Comment: why do you have parameters and static fields by the same name?

Comment: I am expecting print indexes of ch1 and ch2 when they will be present in the  String text

Comment: This code doesn't print anything... Instead, it returns the lowest index either `ch1` or `ch2` are having in the given `String`.

Comment: This was already answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519087/equality-of-string-characters-and-usual-character-dont-work-how-to-get-indexe). If the first character appears in the string, you are never evaluating whether the second character appears, because you exit the method when you do `return i;`. You need to save the indexes in a data structure (i.e. an array) and return the array instead of each index separately.

Comment: You should be using logical OR operator `||`:  ```char c = text.charAt(i);if (c == ch1 || c == ch2) {return i;}```

Comment: *print* and *return* are not same thing. Try to describe in more detail what your application (or its specific fragment) should do and when.

Comment: The question does not clarify what the intended behaviour is.  Please provide some input and expected output examples to improve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know the position of both char1 and char2.

The way you have written your logic, it can only return one value.

You need to remove the return statement and collect the results in some variable.

Then return that variable instead at the end.

or something like this should work:

```
  public class TestIndexOf {
    
       // private static String text;
       // private  static char ch1, ch2;
    
      public static void printIndex(String text, char ch1, char ch2) {
            int count = 0;
            boolean isCharAIndexNotPrinted = true;
            boolean isCharBIndexNotPrinted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
              if(count==2)
                 break;
              if (text.charAt(i) == ch1 && isCharAIndexNotPrinted) {
                count++;
                isCharAIndexNotPrinted = false;
                System.out.println("char1 is " + i);
              }
               if (text.charAt(i) == ch2 && isCharBIndexNotPrinted) {
                count++;
                isCharBIndexNotPrinted = false;
                System.out.println("char2 is " + i);
              }
          }
      }
    }
```